# How to implement the Perlin noise in Raphael.js?

Tags: raphael, effect, perlin-noise

I want to create an implementation of the [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) in Raphael.js. To demonstrate the effect, here's an [example implementation using Flash-AS3](http://atto.s2.pf-x.net/~atto/cgi-bin/up/img/6444.swf).

A few notes:

- The result does not have to match the example perfectly, a similar rendering is good enough.
- I want to place the effect inside a circle shape.
- I am using Raphael 2.01, Firefox 12.0, on Windows XP

I have searched for methods of implementing this on Google, but can't seem to find any. How can this be done?

Comment: Something like this: http://zreference.com/canvas-perlin-noise/? I know it's not using Raphael, but it seems to work quite nice.

Comment: Thank you Robar, I'm trying to convert the code to Raphaël.

Answer (score 2):

Raphael is a vector library - not a very good choise to implement raster graphics effect. It is sure possible to do this, but that solution would be inefficient, because you have to implement pixels in vector - probably, as small dots or squares.

Consider using `<canvas>` element and pure JS instead.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I understood. Vector is not suitable for fine dot expression.